# how to replace the last special character when I press a new one in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Example:**

if the main input value like this "1+23+ " then
I need to replace the last special character with a new one
suppose I click new special characters like minus, multiplication, and divide symbol, etc.

**my expected output:**

- when I click the minus symbol > "1+23- "
- when I click the multiplication symbol > "1+23* "

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="Main">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="1" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="2" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="3" onclick="Cal(this)">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="+" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="-" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="*" onclick="Cal(this)">

</body>
```

```
<script>

 function Cal(btn)
 {
 document.getElementById("Main").value+=btn.value;
 }

</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dpxarmts/ (also, have you tried anything before posting here? done any research? googled how to get the last character of a string? etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want. I first test the last character of the input string with a regex detecting special characters, and if there is a special character inside the input and if the value of the button you pressed is a also a special character, I delete the last character from the string. And then at the end the value of the button you pressed is appended to the end of the string.

```js
function cal(btn)
{
  let format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
  let input = document.getElementById("Main").value
  if(format.test(input.charAt(input.length - 1)) && format.test(btn.value)){
     input = input.slice(0, -1)
  }
  
  input += btn.value;
  document.getElementById("Main").value = input
}
```

```html
<body>

<input type="text" id="Main">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="1" onclick="cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="2" onclick="cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="3" onclick="cal(this)">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="+" onclick="cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="-" onclick="cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="*" onclick="cal(this)">

</body>
```

You can edit the regex to meet your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** If `last value` is not `number` i.e it is a `symbol` and `current value` is also `not a number`. In short if `last value` is `symbol` and `current value` is also a symbol. In this case you have to remove the `last value` and `append` the `current value`

```js
const display = document.getElementById("Main");
const appendValue = val => display.value += val;
const isNumber = n => !isNaN(parseInt(n));

function Cal(btn) {
  const lastValue = display.value.slice(-1);
  const currentValue = btn.value;

  if (!isNumber(lastValue) && !isNumber(currentValue))
    display.value = display.value.slice(0, display.value.length - 1) + currentValue;
  else appendValue(currentValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Main">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="1" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="2" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="3" onclick="Cal(this)">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="+" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="-" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="*" onclick="Cal(this)">
```

**2)** You only have to append value, if it one of the following:

- If there is no value(empty input) in input and current value is a `number`.
- If `last value` is a `number`.
- If `last value` is not a `number` and `current value` is a `number`

```js
const display = document.getElementById("Main");
const appendValue = val => display.value += val;
const isNumber = n => !isNaN(parseInt(n));

function Cal(btn) {
  const lastValue = display.value.slice(-1);
  const currentValue = btn.value;

  if ((!lastValue && isNumber(currentValue)) ||
    (isNumber(lastValue)) ||
    (!isNumber(lastValue) && isNumber(currentValue))) appendValue(currentValue);
  else display.value = display.value.slice(0, display.value.length - 1) + currentValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Main">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="1" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="2" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="3" onclick="Cal(this)">

<input class="ip" type="button" value="+" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="-" onclick="Cal(this)">
<input class="ip" type="button" value="*" onclick="Cal(this)">
```